# Visual studio runs c++ in a white window rather than console

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want it to run just in the cmd but all I get is this white window. Any help?

Code:

```
//
// pch.cpp
// Include the standard header and generate the precompiled header.
//

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "test";
    return 0;
}
```

[image: looks like this]

Comment: Is it a Win32 console application project? It looks like this is a Windows app and not a console application.

Comment: @Banex it was created as an empty c++ program but when I go on Configuration Manager the platform is Win32 (if that's what you mean)

Comment: Try creating a new project and explicitely choosing "Win32 console application".

Comment: @Banex ah I see it's that simple! If you want you can submit it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio provides different kinds of project you can start with.

You are looking for "Win32 Console Application" which already provides the standard configuration that employs a console.

You can also use an empty C++ project, but then you must find all the required settings that enable the console environment.